# Excel Evaluate with table cell reference

Tags: excel, vba

I need Evaluate a function and I'm using (as posted in another question):

```
 Function Eval(aFunction As String)
    Application.Volatile
    Eval = Evaluate(aFunction)
 End Function
```

This works well when the cell reference is like "B15", for example aFormula = "B15*10".

But, I'm working inside a table and I wish to use references like "[@X]", where X is a column header, for example aFormula = "[@X]*10". This returns a error (#VALUE!).

There are a solution? Thanks

Comment: What happens if you select the column header with a mouse as a function parameter? Something like this for me - `=Eval(Tabelle1[[#Kopfzeilen];[123]]*110)` ?

Comment: `Evaluate` has no context in which to evaluate which row of the table you are referring to.